# Explain the output. It is printing next alphabet of every alphabet

Tags: c, pointers, increment, decrement

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char arr[]  = "abcdef";
  char *ptr  = arr;


 while(*ptr != '\0')
     ++*ptr++;
  printf("%s %s",arr,ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Output: bcdefg

It is printing next alphabet of every alphabet given.
What exactly is happening?

Comment: I'm an amateur. Any idea? @haccks

Comment: Try `printf("[%s] [%s]\n", arr, ptr);`

Comment: what I assumed was                                                                             ++*p++ 
1. Dereference 
2. Increment the value
3. Increment the address. Am I correct?

Comment: @pmg it is printing the array [bcdefg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three operators here suffix `++`, prefix `++`, and indirection `*`.

Suffix `++` has higher precedence that the other two and will be evaluated first. But when using suffix `++`, the value computation is sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value, that is incrementing the pointer. So the pointer `ptr` will get incremented, but the value used in other two operands `++` and `*`, will be the old one.

Prefix `++` and indirection operators have the same precedence, but are evaluated from right to left. So indirection `*` goes first and then prefix `++` increments the value of the object pointer `ptr` points to.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to understand what this statement does

```
 ++*ptr++;
```

which is parsed as

```
 ++(*(ptr++));
```

It increments the *value* that `ptr` points to and also increments the `ptr`.

The short answer is: don't write code like that :)

Comment: thank u. It was asked in some competitive exam @Blue Moon